# Bot framework is not calling the sendGame method in the telegram

Tags: node.js, botframework, telegram, rest

I am using the `bot framework rest API` and `channelData` to send the game to `telegram`. But the framework returns `200` and still it doesn't show any message on the `telegram` side, I don't know what I am doing wrong here, Pasting the code below for setting up the channelData:

```
    const channel_data = { method: 'sendGame', parameters: { game_short_name: 'gamename' } };
    let payload = {
      type: type, 
      from: {
        id: telegramResponse.recipient.id,
        name: telegramResponse.recipient.name
      },
      recipient: {
        id: telegramResponse.from.id,
        name: telegramResponse.from.name
      },
       conversation: {
        id: telegramResponse.conversation.id
      },
      text: text, channelData: channel_data
    };
    return payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes I am still researching this issue.

Comment: Did you see the comment I made on June 24?